# Magento: Adding a JS file to the head in an Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, magento

I am calling a controller using Ajax. The controller function is called testAction(). This works nice, the function gets called. Now I want to add JS to the header in that function. My approach was this:

I created a handle, which adds my JS file to the header:

```
<my_handle>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>somefolder/myjs.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</my_handle>
```

Now I added code to my controller to add this handle in the Ajax call, like this.

```
$layout = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
$layout->addHandle('my_handle');
```

Normally this works pretty good, but since its an Ajax call, it doesnt seem to work (file is not included after the call returned). So the question is: How can I add a JavaScript file to the head in an Ajax call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already calling the controller via AJAX you could just load the Javascript using jQuery/Javascript:

**Using jQuery:**

**Method:** jQuery.getScript()
**Description:** Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

See the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for more information.

**Using prototype:**

```
var head;
var script;

head = $$('head')[0];
if (head) {
    script = new Element('script', { type: 'text/javascript', src: 'dynamic.js' });
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

See [here](http://proto-scripty.wikidot.com/prototype%3ahow-to-load-scripts-dynamically) for additional info.

Comment: How would I do it using Prototype JS?

Comment: Updated answer with the Prototype JS method

Comment: Perfect, gonna try it in some minutes, but it looks promising so far!

Comment: Its included, but the content cant be accessed. I have a variable in my JS file and try to use it, but that fails. How would I access the var? Lets call it myVar.

Comment: Just put the variable outside the script and pass it as an argument to the methods inside the script?